# Noobs boot - no other systems visible internet connection through WiFi

Tags: boot-issues, noobs

I can't see other systems than raspbian on noobs installation window. RPI  is connected through internet by WiFi - no possible connection through rj45. Is it possible to obtain network installers (other systems) using WiFi?

Comment: Are you sure the system is actually on your wifi network? Have you been asked for any wifi configuration?  If not, it is impossible for the system to be online.  Searching around a bit, I have not seen a clear statement that it will work out of the box via wifi, unfortunately.

Comment: wipi has been configured after raspbian instalation, and i have access to internet.

Comment: I think the Raspbian setup would be distinct from NOOBs itself.  I'm actually not a NOOBs user so I can't be of much help WRT that.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why theres only Raspian, 512MB space partition, and boot to scratch is because you need a direct connection (Ethernet). Or you may be using the offline only files and didn't download the online only files.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is NOT possible to connect to download another Operating System using Wi-Fi. You'll have to use an Ethernet Cable.

If you cannot see all the Operating Systems you would expect, go to the Raspberry Pi website and then download the NOOBS package there, as it would be the newest version.

Having said that, using an Ethernet Cable to download an OS is probably a reasonable idea. Ethernet connection are considerably quicker than using a wireless connection.